# Trying to add with method, believe something is not instantiating

Tags: c#

When I type in the textbox, I am wanting it to add the numbers, instead if I type (for example) 12, and click deposit again, it only shows 12. I think this is because it seems to think thats its 0 plus 12 everytime. Something doesnt seem to be instantiating correctly. I think. Can anyone point out what I am doing incorrectly?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_deposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double input;
        input = double.Parse((putin.Text));
        BankAccount a = new BankAccount(input);
        aMtBox.Text = a.AccountBalance.ToString();
    }
}

public class BankAccount
{
    private double num1;
    private double accountBalance;

    public BankAccount(double input)
    {
        num1 = input;
        Deposit();
    }

    public double Num1
    {
        set {num1 = value;}
        get {return num1;}}

    public double AccountBalance
    {
        get {return accountBalance;}
        set {accountBalance = value;}}

    public void Deposit()
    {
        accountBalance = accountBalance + num1;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `BankAccount` each time the button is clicked - so `accountBalance` will be 0.0 (the default value for a field of type `double`). How did you expect it to "know" about the previous balance?

It's entirely possible that you should have an *instance* variable of type `BankAccount` in your form. You should also consider what the `num1` instance variable in `BankAccount` is meant to represent. The name certainly doesn't tell us anything. It feels like it should actually just be a parameter to the `Deposit` method.

Additionally, for currency values you should never use `double` - use either `decimal`, or an integer type to represent the number of cents (or pence, or whatever). You don't want to get into the normal binary floating point issue.

At this point, your method would become something like:

```
// I hate the VS-generated event names, but...
private void btn_deposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Use decimal.TryParse, and handle invalid input cleanly.
    decimal newDeposit = decimal.Parse(putin.Text);
    account.Deposit(newDeposit);
    aMtBox.Text = account.AccountBalance.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I think the idea i had going for was num1 was supposed to be the input that the user typed in. I am very new to programming. A lot of concepts  go beyond me and since ive only programmed for 4 months Ive been trying to keep things basic and progress slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a BankAccount field for the form which is initialized with the form.  Should look something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BankAccount account;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        account = new BankAccount(0);
    }

    private void btn_Deposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        account.Num1 = double.Parse((putin.Text));
        account.Deposit();
        aMtBox.Text = account.AccountBalance.ToString();
    }

}
```

On a side note, Input should be validated, and the BankAccount class refactored to something like:

```
class BankAccount
{
    private double num1;
    private double accountBalance;

    public BankAccount(double startingBalance)
    {
        accountBalance = startingBalance;
    }

    public double AccountBalance
    {
        get {return accountBalance;}
        set {accountBalance = value;}
    }

    public void Deposit(double depositAmount)
    {
        accountBalance += depositAmount;
    }
}
```